# Show a polynomial of degree 4 in 7 variables is positive

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, positive-definite

I am trying to find out if the following homogeneous polynomial of degree 4 in 7 variables ($a,b,c,d,x,y$ and $z$) is positive (except when all variables are zero). After running numerical optimization, I am quite convinced about its positivity. But I am not able to use sum of squares to prove it. Some literature search led me to papers on Hilbert's 17th problem, but still I am not sure how to prove it. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

$$a^2(x^2 + y^2 + z^2) + (b^2 + c^2 + d^2/2) x^2 + (b^2 + c^2/2 + 
    d^2) y^2 + (b^2/2 + c^2 + d^2) z^2 + 
 4 a (b x y + c x z + d y z) + 2 (c d x y + b d x z + b c y z).$$

Comment: This is quadratic in $a,b,c,d$ and also in $x,y,z$. So it boils down to showing that some $3\times 3$ matrix with entries quadratic forms in $a,b,c,d$ is always positive definite, that is, its principal minors are positive.

Comment: Yes, so at least we need to show the determinant of a $3\times 3$ or $4\times 4$ symbolic matrix is positive, that is, a polynomial of degree 8 in 3 variables, or a polynomial of degree 6 in 4 variables is positive. Still, the form of sum of squares is not clear to me and the question seems to be not easier....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix $x,y,z$ and write half the Hessian matrix of the quadratic form in $a,b,c,d.$ The entries are quadratic forms in $x,y,z,$ and it is symmetric.

In fact, it is equal to the Gram matrix $B B^T$ of basis
$$
B =
\left(
\begin{array}{ccccccccc}
x&y&z&0&0&0&0&0&0 \\
y&x&0&\frac{z}{2}&\frac{z}{2}&0&0&0&0 \\
z&0&x&0&0&\frac{y}{2}&\frac{y}{2}&0&0 \\
0&z&y&0&0&0&0&\frac{x}{2}&\frac{x}{2} \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
This $B$ has rank $4$ unless $x,y,z=0.$ So $BB^T$ is positive definite.

You can find many examples of rectangular basis matrices at [NEBE SLOANE](http://www.math.rwth-aachen.de/~Gabriele.Nebe/LATTICES/)